# Using an escape sequence that can't fit in its related type

Tags: c++, literals

wI read in C++ Primer that using a literal that is larger than its largest related type is an error, but found on the internet that this is not the case for escape sequences.

So, is using an escape sequence that can't fit in its related type an error or undefined behavior?
E.g. `\x1234`. Assuming the Latin-1 character set and that a byte is 8 bits, this can't fit in a `char` but still is valid-written literal.

Comment: VS142 gives me an error if too big.

Comment: The **B** programming language supports multi-character literals.  In **C**, some compilers still support them as an extension, but they are not in the C standard.  In **C++**, some compilers still support them as an extension, but they are not in the C++ standard.  The type of a `'abcd'` multi-character literal is **int**.

Answer (score 3):

This is implementation defined behavior for `char` and `wchar_t`, and undefined behavior for `char8_t`, `char16_t` and `char32_t` per [[lex.ccon]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.ccon#8)

> The escape `\ooo` consists of the backslash followed by one, two, or three octal digits that are taken to specify the value of the desired character. The escape `\xhhh` consists of the backslash followed by x followed by one or more hexadecimal digits that are taken to specify the value of the desired character. There is no limit to the number of digits in a hexadecimal sequence. A sequence of octal or hexadecimal digits is terminated by the first character that is not an octal digit or a hexadecimal digit, respectively. **The value of a character literal is implementation-defined if it falls outside of the implementation-defined range defined for `char` (for character literals with no prefix) or `wchar_­t` (for character literals prefixed by L). [ Note: If the value of a character literal prefixed by `u`, `u8`, or `U` is outside the range defined for its type, the program is ill-formed. — end note ]**

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

---

The note is non-normative but paragraphs [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.ccon#3), [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.ccon#4), and [5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.ccon#5) from the same section cover the text from the note.

Comment: The note indicates that the intent is that a numeric escape sequence that specifies a value too large for the range of the type is ill-formed for `UTF-8`, `UTF-16`, and `UTF-32` literals.  I agree that we're missing proper normative wording.

There is at least one related core issue here:
- [CWG #2333 - Escape sequences in UTF-8 character literals](https://wg21.link/cwg2333)